# Не отображается PhotoImage в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пишу приложение на питоне, понадобилось вставить изображение. 
Вставил, как `Label` с `image`, но изображение просто не отображается.

Что можно сделать в этом случае?

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
#SE FUNCS


import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now

ee = Button (root 
        ,text="click")
ee.place(x=10, y=10)
imagei = Label(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("h.png")) )
imagei.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pygame import mixer

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")

mixer.init()
#SE FUNCS

now = datetime.datetime.now

ee = Button(
    root,
    text="click"
)
ee.place(x=50, y=200)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Ok.png"))
imagei = Label(image=image)
imagei.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так тоже не работает. Может ли быть проблема в компьютере, с которого приложение запускается?

Comment: Я некорректно вставил код из ответа, извиняюсь. Всё работает, спасибо!